# Вопросы по верстке

Tags: html, вёрстка

1. Как правильно сделать меню и почему?
   [Вариант 1](https://jsfiddle.net/anonymweb/ept2cza2/)

   ```
   <nav>
       <a href="#"></a>
       <a href="#"></a>
       <a href="#"></a>
       <a href="#"></a>
   </nav>
   ```

   ---

   или [Вавриант 2](https://jsfiddle.net/anonymweb/c22yr83g/)

   ```
   <nav>
       <ul>
           <li><a href="#"></a></li>
           <li><a href="#"></a></li>
           <li><a href="#"></a></li>
           <li><a href="#"></a></li>
       </ul>
   </nav>
   ```
2. Можно ли к семантическим блокам, использующимся для построения «структуры документа» (н-р: `header`, `main`, `section` и др.) применять классы отвечающие за построение сетки (н-р: `row`, `col`, `wrapper` и т.п.)? Или для сетки лучше использовать `div`?
3. Является ли ошибкой наличие семантических блоков без применения к ним каких-либо стилей. Или это оправдывается семантически правильной разметкой?

Comment: [**Разделили бы лучше свой вопрос на несколько**](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/q/3169/199934). Спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

1. Допустимы оба варианта.
2. Можно.
3. Не является, но и не оправдывается.

Все на самом деле просто, главное правило - все должно быть логично. header в заголовке, footer в подвале, nav для навигации, ul/ol - для списков и так далее. Хотите стилизовать или еще как-то использовать элемент - присваивайте id и/или класс. Удачи в работе.

Answer (score 1):

Важно понимать что дизайн блоков определяется CSS, то есть внешний вид блоков никоим образом не может нарушить семантику и валидацию HTML.

Это ответ на 2 и 3 вопросы.

По поводу 1 вопроса, если у вас возникают сомнения в валидности вашего кода вы всегда можете обратиться к [W3C HTML валидатору](https://validator.w3.org/#validate_by_input) и [W3C CSS валидатору](https://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/#validate_by_input+with_options)

Answer (score 0):

В html нет четкого понятия правильно/неправильно, есть "рекомендации" W3C и некие "стандарты", но каждый разработчик браузера, сам решает, как интерпретировать эти рекомендации, поэтому есть множество исключений.

Согласно рекомендации правильно использовать 2 вариант, это семантично.

Теги `<header>`, `<footer>`, `<nav>`, `<main>` и пр. по большей части являются блочными элементами, никто не мешает вам работать с ними также как с `<div>`
Поэтому да можно и так `<header id="header" class="header">` или как вам более угодно

Comment: Есть **четкие** стандарты. Вроде не вложенности элементов (например form в  form). Не валидную разметку гугл например может исключить из поисковой выдачи. А отображение в браузерах может быть не верным.

Comment: Да какие же они четкие? И причем тут гугл и его поисковая выдача? =)

Comment: Вы считаете допустимым нарушать рекомендации W3C и нарушать валидность разметки? Для каждого тега есть семантические стандарты нарушение которых вызовет не верное отображение например e-mail писем

Comment: ))) Да причем тут это? сами пишите "рекомендации" и называете их "четкими" стандартами, что за замена понятий.
Тут вообще человек задал вопрос касаемо технической составляющей.

А следовать или не следовать "рекомендациям" каждый волен решать сам. Ведь все зависит от задачи.
Если у нас промо-сайт, который должен быть в топе поиска, то это одна реализация, а если у нас закрытая CRM для внутреннего использования в предприятии, и требуется, чтобы даже у Тёти Зины в 6 эксплорере открывалось, то тут даже табличной версткой можно не брезговать.

Comment: Суть в том что рекомендации они только на словах, по сути любое отклонение от стандарта не допустимо, так как **все** веб-обозреватели придерживаются его. Важно понимать что "Рекомендация" в данном случае всего лишь вежливое понятие. И кстати в табличной верстке на самом деле нет ничего плохого, например для форм, так что не стоит быть таким категоричным с ней.

Писать не валидный код не есть хорошо хотя бы по тому что вы не один его поддерживате. Так что не стоит бросаться такими утверждениями как в вашем ответе.

Comment: Да плевать всем на стандарты
Выдача гугла https://vk.cc/67vVCe - 20 ошибок
Этот пост https://vk.cc/67vWby - 9 ошибок
Выдача яндекса https://vk.cc/67vXnY - 1 ошибка 3 предупреждения
И о боже мой, сайт W3C https://vk.cc/67vYAt - 8 ошибок, 3 предупреждения.

Расскажите мне вашу прохладную историю еще раз

Comment: Страницы таких крупных ресурсов собираются из десятка разных модулей которые могут нарушать семантику друг друга. Хотя все ошибки что я увидел исключительно из-за обратной совместимости с HTML3-4. К тому же гугл имеет более 13 (!) разных шаблонов для разных устройств для лучшего отображения контента, возможно вы просто использовали не актуальный шаблон. 

Если вам очень хочется писать плохо, ваше право. Но хотя бы не учите этому народ.

Comment: Ага, но вы же сказали есть четкие правила? Какие тогда расхождения и обратная совместимость, если _" все веб-обозреватели придерживаются его"_ **Вы сами себе противоречите** Больше всего понравилось _"возможно вы просто использовали не актуальный шаблон"_ валидатор взял тот html который ему отправил сам гугл в данную секунду, и когда вы перешли по ссылке, он снова сделал валидацию того, что выдал гугл. И второй момент _"собираются из десятка разных модулей"_ особенно актуально для информационного сайта W3C. **И что самое главное** Есть четкие правила русского языка, но вы же им не следуете

Comment: В общем Василий, будьте честны перед собой, следовать "рекомендациям" - это прекрасно и правильно, но называть их "четкими" правилами неуместно.

Comment: Вы либо говорите вещи которые не понимаете, либо делаете вид что вы их не понимаете. Пожалуйста давайте не будем скатываться на спор у кого русский лучше.

Comment: Если вы спрашиваете про обратную совместимость, то вы видимо не понимаете что стандарт развивается и изменяется внося значительные различия. Что касается строгих правил и рекомендаций. Нет evergreen браузеров не следующих рекомендациям, к тому же не все парсеры так интелектуальны как WebKit и Gecko. Отклонение от общей спецификации это всегда плохо для определенной аудитории будь то браузеры, боты или почта. Чем строже вы выполняете рекомендации W3C, тем корректнее верстка. И возможно это только мое мнение (ну ладно еще ранжирующих ботов поисковых систем),

Comment: но чем более серьезно новички будут воспринимать рекомендации, тем чище, читабельные и поддерживаемее будет веб в будущем. Нам уже хватило горе PHP "специалистов", не несите это в разметку.